# Why am I obtaining this Maven error when I try to compile a .car application related to an ESB project containing a single proxy?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I was studying the **VFS** concept and I was trying to implement this tutorial:
https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87712181

but I have some doubts about it:

Starting the ESB with this sample configuration (as explained here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/Setting+Up+the+ESB+Samples#SettingUptheESBSamples-Startingasample ) it works fine:

```
wso2ei-samples.bat -sn 254
```

So basically I have the **254** sample that is defined in this file on my PC:

```
C:\WSO2\EI\6.3.0\samples\service-bus\synapse_sample_254.xml
```

I think that starting EI with the previous **-sn 253** parameter will execute this flow. How exactly works? My idea is that it take the proxy into this file **synapse_sample_254.xml** and automatically deploy it after that the EI is started. But I am abslolutly not sure about this assertion.

Anyay in this way it works.

The problem is that I am trying to implement this behavior inside an ESB project creating a proxy and in this case it is not working.

What I have done:

1) I create an **ESB Config Project** (named **VFSTest**).

2) Into this project I create a **custom proxy**. New --> Proxy Service --> Create A New Proxy Service. I set the "Proxy Service Name" to **VFSProxy**. Then I chose **Custom Proxy** as value for the **Proxy Service Type** dropdown. So my new proxy is created.

3) I insert the following code for this proxy (using the **Source** tab):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <proxy name="StockQuoteProxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="vfs">
        <target>
            <endpoint>
                <address format="soap12" uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
            </endpoint>
            <inSequence/>
            <outSequence>
                <property expression="fn:concat(fn:substring-after(get-property('MessageID'), 'urn:uuid:'), '.xml')" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
                <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
                <send>
                    <endpoint>
                        <address uri="vfs:file://C:\Users\nobil\OneDrive\Documenti\WSO2\RESOURCES\VFSTest\out"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </send>
            </outSequence>
            <faultSequence/>
        </target>
        <publishWSDL preservePolicy="true" uri="file:samples/service-bus/resources/proxy/sample_proxy_1.wsdl"/>
        <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file://C:\Users\nobil\OneDrive\Documenti\WSO2\RESOURCES\VFSTest\in</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/xml</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file://C:\Users\nobil\OneDrive\Documenti\WSO2\RESOURCES\VFSTest\failure</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*\.xml</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file://C:\Users\nobil\OneDrive\Documenti\WSO2\RESOURCES\VFSTest\success</parameter>
    </proxy>
</definitions>
```

(I only replaced the same line replaced in the previous sample related to the directory and the endpoint on my PC, it is the same code).

So now I have my ESB project containing this proxy.

Then I create a new **Composite Application Project** named **VFSTestCAP** and I add the previous **VFSTest** ESB project as dependency.

Finnally I select the **pom.xml** file of this **VFSTestCAP** project and I do a **Run As --> Maven Install** to build the **.car** application that have to be deployed on my server.

The problem is that doing in this way Maven fails, this is my stack trace:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building VFSTestCAP 1.0.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (397 B at 0.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (843 B at 0.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (843 B at 0.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 1.4 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (402 B at 0.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 1.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (491 B at 0.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 2.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 2.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (366 B at 0.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (663 B at 0.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (663 B at 0.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (394 B at 0.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (749 B at 0.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/maven-metadata.xml (749 B at 0.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/com/example/VFSTest/proxy-service/VFSProxy/1.0.0/VFSProxy-1.0.0.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/com/example/VFSTest/proxy-service/VFSProxy/1.0.0/VFSProxy-1.0.0.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/example/VFSTest/proxy-service/VFSProxy/1.0.0/VFSProxy-1.0.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.example.VFSTest.proxy-service:VFSProxy:xml:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/com/example/VFSTest/proxy-service/VFSProxy/1.0.0/VFSProxy-1.0.0.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/com/example/VFSTest/proxy-service/VFSProxy/1.0.0/VFSProxy-1.0.0.xml
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/example/VFSTest/proxy-service/VFSProxy/1.0.0/VFSProxy-1.0.0.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.597 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-12T11:21:42+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/295M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project VFSTestCAP: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.VFSTestCAP:VFSTestCAP:carbon/application:1.0.0: Could not find artifact com.example.VFSTest.proxy-service:VFSProxy:xml:1.0.0 in wso2-nexus (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

As you can see the error seems to be:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project VFSTestCAP: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.VFSTestCAP:VFSTestCAP:carbon/application:1.0.0: Could not find artifact com.example.VFSTest.proxy-service:VFSProxy:xml:1.0.0 in wso2-nexus (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/) -> [Help 1]
```

Why is it trying to retrieve the VFSProxy from Nexus? It is defined into my ESB project as XML flow.

What could be the problem? What am I missing? How can I fix it and create my car deployable application?

Comment: Have you tried the Export Composite Application Project from Eclipse (right click on the CAR projectt) ?
Also, can you share the ESB projects' artifact.xml and the CAR projects  pom.xml?  There might be a name mismatch between the name you gave your new proxy and the name you copied with the code from the sample proxy (as shown in your post)

Comment: @ophychius you make my day mate, it was a problem related to the proxy name. Now it works...but now I am obtaining another error after deployment...now I am investigating

Comment: Glad to help, I'll actually put it in an answer for posterity's sake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a name mismatch between the name you gave your new proxy and the name you copied with the code from the sample proxy (as shown in your post).

Eclipse automatically makes an entry in the artifacts.xml file when you generate the new Proxy. If the name is not the same as the name in the code of your proxy can cause a problem when the maven is trying to resolve the dependencies of the CAR project.

The best way to check this is to compare the dependencies in the pom file with the artifacts.xml in the ESB project.  And if you make name changes make sure you match the name in the actual proxy definition (to prevent future mixups)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to build the proxy project the same way you did with the capp project. Now if you try to build the capp, it would succeed because the relevant dependency will be in your local maven repository.

PS: If you want to use maven to build the car file, it's better to use maven multi module project. This will first install the artifacts and then the capp accordingly. Otherwise, simply exporting the capp would be sufficient.